# Can I use a dynamic mapping to unpack keyword arguments in Python?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Long story short, I want to call format with arbitrarily named arguments, which will preform a lookup.

```
'{Thing1} and {other_thing}'.format(**my_mapping)
```

I've tried implementing my_mapping like this:

```
class Mapping(object):
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return 'Proxied: %s' % key
my_mapping = Mapping()
```

Which works as expected when calling `my_mapping['anything']`. But when passed to format() as shown above I get:

```
TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Mapping
```

I tried subclassing `dict` instead of `object`, but now calling `format()` as shown raises `KeyError`. I even implemented `__contains__` as `return True`, but still `KeyError`.

So it seems that `**` is not just calling `__getitem__` on the object passed in. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: `**` couldn't really work with just `__getitem__`. What items would it get when passing arguments to a function that takes any keyword arguments (`**kwargs`)?

Comment: This may be as good as it gets for python < 3.2.

`'{0[Thing1]} and {0[other_thing]}'.format(my_mapping)`

It does work at least.

Comment: In general there is no need to comment on your own question e.g., you could update your question to specify that you use Python 2.6.5 if it is relevant or post your last comment as an answer (and if nothing better turns up in a couple of days then accept it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2 you can do this using `string.Formatter` class.

```
>>> class Mapping(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         return 'Proxied: %s' % key
...
>>> my_mapping = Mapping()
>>> from string import Formatter
>>> Formatter().vformat('{Thing1} and {other_thing}', (), my_mapping)
'Proxied: Thing1 and Proxied: other_thing'
>>>
```

`vformat` takes 3 args: the format string, sequence of positional fields and mapping of keyword fields. Since positional fields weren't needed, I used an empty tuple `()`.

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.2+:

```
'{Thing1} and {other_thing}'.format_map(my_mapping)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but it was added in python 3.2 (Just looked that up)

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit of necromancy, but I recently came across this problem, and this SO question was the first result. I wasn't happy with using `string.Formatter`, and wanted it to **Just Work** *(TM)*.

If you implement a `keys()` function for your class as well as `__getitem__()`, then `**my_mapping` will work.

I.e:

```
class Mapping(object):

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return 'Proxied: %s' % key

  def keys(self):
    return proxy.keys()
```

where

```
>>> my_mapping = Mapping()
>>> my_mapping.keys()
['Thing1','other_thing',...,'Thing2']
```

will result in a successful mapping that will work with `.format`.

Apparently (though I haven't actually looked at the source for `str.format`), it appears to use `keys()` to get a list of keys, then map the identifiers given in the string to those keys, then use `__getitem__()` to retrieve the specified values.

Hope this helps.

*EDIT*:

If you are in @aaron-mcmillin's position, and the key set is large, then a possible approach is to not generate a full set of keys, but generate a smaller subset. This only works of course if you know you will only need to format a small subset.

I.e:

```
class Mapping(object):
  ...
  def keys(self):
    return ['Thing1','other_thing', 'Thing2']
```

Comment: That's neat, but as my comment says above, my key space is all the CN's in my LDAP, and the number of lookups per string will be minimal. So I don't really want to generate all the keys.

Comment: In that case, the solution doesn't fit for you, but it is still an entirely valid (and correct) answer. It does nothing but provide standard python magic functions that a `format`-able class would provide.  I completely understand that if you have a large key set (and if your LDAP server is connected over the network), you may not want to expend the cycles required to generate the keyset.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could come up with:

If you have a custom mapping object that you want to pass to a func taking key-word arguments, then it must have a set of keys (which may be dynamically generated, but it must be a finite set), and it must be able to map those keys somehow. So, if you can assume that it will have an `__iter__` to get the keys, and a `__getitem__` that will succeed for each of those keys, e.g.:

```
class Me(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(['a', 'b', 'c'])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return 12
```

Say the function is:

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    print kwargs, type(kwargs)
```

Then we can pass it along by making a dict:

```
m = Me()
myfunc(**dict((k, m[k]) for k in m))
```

Resulting in:

```
{'a': 12, 'c': 12, 'b': 12} <type 'dict'>
```

Apparently this must be the way it's done... even if you pass in an object derived from `dict`, the function will still have a `dict` for the kwargs:

```
class Me(dict): pass

m = Me()
print type(m) #prints <class '__Main__.Me'>

def myfunc(**kwargs):
    print type(kwargs)
myfunc(**m) #prints <type 'dict'>
```

Since it sounds like you wanted to do something like return a value based on what the key was, without having a particular set of keys in mind, it seems like you can't use the `format` function.

Comment: Well, the particular set of keys in mind is all the cn's in my LDAP, which is a bit overkill to extract into a dictionary for one or two lookups.

Comment: @AaronCroyle: yeah, basically this answer is saying you can't use the `format` function for what you wanna do.